# MongoDB filtering nested structure

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following data structure:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("630bd746956bba0f6f0ba448"),
    "a": [
      {
        "b": [
          [
            [
              {
                "c": "aaa"
              }
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
```

How can I filter all documents with the value `aaa` for their nested c property? I tried using this query:
`db.collection.find({"a.b.c": "aaa"})`
but it doesn't work.

[Link to Mongo playground.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VD7xyBPCWXd)

Comment: Sniff test alert:   `b` is an array of arrays of arrays?   Double check your data design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to match documents that contain an array field, you need to use `$elemMatch` operator. Try this query out:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "a.b": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "c": "aaa"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Documentation for reference: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Answer (score 2):

To search in an array, you need to use `$elemMatch`, and where you have nested arrays, the query will be:

```bash
db.collection.find({
  "a": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "b": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "c": "aaa"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Link to Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K9EtsbaYG9L)